# Google Sheets query sum counted columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to count all cells that match a regex patterns. So far I've come up with a solution using a `query` per column, and then using `SUM()` to sum the counts over the different columns.

This rather unwieldy, a change in the query means I need to change a lot of cells and partial formulas. Ideally, I have a solution that sums the counts in the query, or something else that better maintainable.

What I have now:

```
=sum(
  query(I10:I19,"select count(I) where I matches '^[A-Za-z\s]{4,64}$' label count(I) ''"),
  query(J10:J19,"select count(J) where J matches '^[A-Za-z\s]{4,64}$' label count(J) ''"),
  query(K10:K19,"select count(K) where K matches '^[A-Za-z\s]{4,64}$' label count(K) ''"),
  [etc. etc.]
)
```

What I'd ideally have:

```
=query(I10:L19,"select sum(count(J),count(K),count(L)) where L matches '^[A-Za-z0-9\s\-]{4,64}$' OR J matches '^[A-Za-z0-9\s\-]{4,64}$' OR K matches '^[A-Za-z0-9\s\-]{4,64}$' label sum(*) ''")
```

but nesting `count()`s in `sum()` seems not to be supported.

Is there a way to achieve something like this?

Note that the `label count(X) ''`  is to remove any label and header, and to ge the result in the first cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably replace your query with a completely different formula.

Please try the following one

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(REGEXMATCH(I10:K19,"^[A-Za-z\s]{4,64}$"),true))
```

If you really insist on using a query try the following

```
=query(flatten(I10:K19),"select count(Col1) where Col1 matches '^[A-Za-z\s]{4,64}$' label count(Col1) ''")
```

*(The regex is just a copy of the one you shared. If still in need, please share a test sheet.)*

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)
- [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)
- `flaten`(Undocumented)

Comment: Out of curiosity. Has the `ArrayFormula` formula worked for you as expected?

Answer (score 2):

### You can use string concatenation

The query is just a string, so you could make your regex query live in a separate cell, which would make your formula look like this, if your regex was in a sheet called "Regex" and in the cell `A1` with the value `="'^[A-Za-z\s]{4,64}$'"`

```
=sum(
  query(I10:I19,"select count(I) where I matches" & Regex!A1 & "label count(I) ''"),
  query(J10:J19,"select count(J) where J matches" & Regex!A1 & "label count(J) ''"),
  query(K10:K19,"select count(K) where K matches" & Regex!A1 & "label count(K) ''"),
  [etc. etc.]
)
```

#### Reference

- [Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

> The value for query must either be enclosed in quotation marks or be a reference to a cell containing the appropriate text.